# Django - env folder not getting created while using VS 2015 and python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using VS 2015 and python 2.7 to create a Web application using Django. VS 2015 asked to create a virtual env but I am getting the following error and the env folder is not getting created;

```
Installing 'pip' package manager.
pip is already available.
'pip' was installed successfully.
Installing 'pip' package manager.
pip is already available.
'pip' was installed successfully.
Collecting https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317969
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
 status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 299, in run
 requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
  ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file
 session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
hashes=hashes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 649, in unpack_http_url
hashes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 842, in _download_http_url
stream=True,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 480, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 378, in request
return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 46, in send
resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 447, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: ('_ssl.c:574: The handshake operation timed out',)
System.InvalidOperationException: Virtual environment was not created at     'C:\Users\Jeri_Dabba\Google     Drive\Python\Django\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\'
 at Microsoft.PythonTools.Project.VirtualEnv.<CreateAndInstallDependencies>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at Microsoft.PythonTools.Project.PythonProjectNode.<CreateOrAddVirtualEnvironment>d__148.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.PythonTools.Project.AddVirtualEnvironmentOperation.<Run>d__10.MoveNext()
```

Could anyone please help me out with this as I am new to django.

Comment: An SSL/TLS connection failed. This could be a temporary network or server failure.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yeah I am behind a proxy, is there any to bypass the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the proxy configuration in your environment. For Windows, this means setting the environment variables. Simply search for `environment variables` in the Start menu, and click on `Edit environment variables for your account`.

You need to add two environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`, the value is in the format `http://user:password@proxy.server.com:port`.

For example, if your proxy server is `proxy.example.com` and is listening on port `8080`, your value is `http://user:password@proxy.example.com:8080`

Check with your network administrator for the exact settings for your environment.

Once you have updated the variables (and clicked OK), it is very important to **restart visual studio** otherwise the variables will not be read.